# Database design for facebook oriented application?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7

My website will be fully Facebook oriented, and will be containing data only scrapped from FB. I am using the below DB design currently but I am not sure what fields are need to be recorded and what aren't. Pleas help me.

Current design :

```
Tablename = Users:-

id = FB id
fname = FB first name
lname = FB last name
email = email account
DOB = Date of birth
Country = Country
db.relationship = Tablename(Friends)

Tablename = Friends:-

id = auto increment id
fname = Friend's first name
lname = Friend's last name
email = Friend's email
DOB = Friend's DOB
Country = Friend's country
LastMessage = Custom entry filled by app
userid = db.relationship.FK(user.id)
```

So am I missing anything here, or this itself is good to go.. I read about oauth token or something.. whether that needs to be pushed down?

Comment: That sounds like a crazy design. Store everyone in users and then have a friends table which contains user_id, friend_id

Comment: Actually the users table holds the user's details who have registered to the app and the Friends table holds the details of the User's Friends' details...

Comment: But what if a user's friends have registered? Have a flag in Users table if the user registered or not. And for v2.0 it doesn't matter because you can't get friends that are not registered anyway

Comment: I haven't thought about that yet.... but will add.. coming back to the base question.. what else do I need to record in the database for a User..